# Remove element before inserting with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove the span with child span from #data, so that #result contains "Only text left" ?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data">Only text left <span class='price'>remove this<span>   €0,00</span> </span>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var nhtml = $('#data').html();
    $('#result').html(nhtml);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: you set the #data html to `Only text left` like `$('#data').html('Only text left')`

Comment: Problem here, content is dynamic. This is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter text nodes from it using **[`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)** and **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)**, then get text content by **[`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/)**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data">Only text left <span class='price'>remove this<span>   €0,00</span> </span>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var nhtml = $('#data')
      .contents() // get all child nodes including  text and comment node
      .filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3; // filter text node from it
      }).text(); // get the text content from it
    $('#result').html(nhtml);
  });
</script>
```

---

Or clone the element using **[`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)** and remove the span, then get the html content

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data">Only text left <span class='price'>remove this<span>   €0,00</span> </span>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var nhtml = $('#data')
      .clone() // clone the element
      .find('.price') // get the span
      .remove() // remove the span
      .end() // back to cloned element
      .html(); // get the html content from cloned element 
    $('#result').html(nhtml);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @Kurdt94 : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used .remove() function to remove it, you can refer the fiddle link below

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".price").remove();
  var nhtml = $('#data').html();
  $('#result').html(nhtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data">Only text left <span class='price'>remove this<span>   €0,00</span> </span> </div>
<div id="result"> </div>
```

[Jsfiddle link for solution](https://jsfiddle.net/utsavoza/aqjy5dnh/)